# Get dB(a) level from AudioKit in swift

Tags: ios, swift, audio, audiokit, decibel

I am attempting to get dB(A) readings from audio recorded from the microphone from AudioKit. I attempt to pass the amplitude tracker into the `AKFFTTap` object, but it always returns an array of zeros when I call `AKFFTTap.fftData`. Does anyone have experience with getting dB(A) values from AudioKit and the microphone.

Comment: Please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: You won't be measuring dBA without a datum point. Furthermore, you'll need to do a significant amount of filtering to the signal. Reading Wikipedia's quite comprehensive article (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decibel) should provide some insight.